# Unable to perform Drag and Drop using selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, drag-and-drop, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to perform dragAndDrop functionality. 
I tried with `dragAndDrop` and `clickAndHold` also. I am able to drag the object to destination, but after that the object comes back to the source position. When i tried with `clickAndHold` object was dragged to the destination location, when i released the `clickAndHold` the object was again came back to the old source location.
I tried with below code as well.

```
builder.clickAndHold(source).moveToElement(destination).release(destination).build().perform();

builder.dragAndDrop(source, destination).build().perform();
```

How can i Handle this issue ???

Comment: can you show the source type code and destination type ?

Comment: I had the same problem. After extensive research on SO and the net, I think this is a Selenium bug. I filed a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6315&thanks=6315&ts=1380031813

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.In order to give a good show,I do like this:

```
builder.clickAndHold(source).build().perform();
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    builder.moveToElement(source,xoffset*i,yoffset).build().perform();//builder.moveToElement(destination,xoffset,yoffset*i).build().perform();
}
builder.release(target).build.perform();
```

The hope can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced problem with drag and drop too.Workded sometimes and failed mostly. You can use the following syntax:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(source).moveToElement(destination).release(hiddenplatform).build();
dragAndDrop.perform();
```

But there's a catch here. You see we have to release on the hidden platform. When we take the xpath for the destination; and we expand we find an **id** with `value=hidden`.

Take that id and create a WebElement and release on that platform.
Works absolutely fine for me now. :)